# Why is the following button/javascript code not working?

Tags: javascript, html, button

The button is visible but does not create the alert. I have already tried linking the JS to an external file but that too doesn't work. I have tried the code on Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

Here is the complete code:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <title> My First Webpage </title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

     <!--       
            function sayHello{
                alert("Hello World");
            }
    //-->

     </script> 

</head>

<body>

    <div id="main_pic">
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
        <a href="about/second.html">Go to second page </a>
        <br><br><br>
        <img src="img/IMG_9115.JPG" alt="Me and my friend" height="300" width="400" />
    </div>
    <div id="list1">
        <h3>Unordered List</h3>
        <ul>
            <li class="color_to_blue">One</li>
            <li class="color_to_blue">Two</li>
            <li id="no_3_red">Three</li>
            <li>Four</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="sayHello()" value="Say Hello World" />

</body>
```

Comment: Would the down voter reveal himself to the general public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your browser has a console in the developer tools. Use it!

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

The syntax for a function declaration is:

- `function` - the keyword
- `identifier` - the function name
- `(`
- argument list
- `)`
- `{`
- function body
- `}`

You missed off `(argument list)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the web console of your browser, it will tell you why.

Specifically, it will tell you you have a syntax error:

```
function sayHello{
// Here ---------^
    alert("Hello World");
}
```

You need `()` there.

Answer (score 0):

You need ()

Your function tokens include brackets.

How can you miss that.

Also always check browser console before posting your question. You can nab some errors quite easily